# Joining 5 tables in SQL in a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

`What I'm trying to return in a set:` The `lessonID`s associated to the `userID` and `schoolID` within a given `startTime` and `endTime`.

This is to be displayed on a calendar. I only want to display the lessons that are associated to the user viewing it for a selected school within the time range they are viewing on the calendar.

This data is just dummy data to show the table structure and data types.

Lesson Table:

```
lessonID  roomFK    startTime                 endTime
   1        2      2014-08-01 13:00:00   2014-08-01 14:00:00 
   2        3      2014-08-01 13:00:00   2014-08-01 14:00:00
```

Room Table:

```
roomID   schoolFK
1            1
2            1
3            2
4            2
```

School Table:

```
schoolID 
   1
   2
```

User Table:

```
userID
  1
  2
  3
```

Lesson/Teacher Junction Table:

```
lessonFK    teacherFK
    1          1
    1          2
    2          3
```

What I've tried:

```
function find_lessons_by_school_id_and_teacher_id_ranged_feed($school_id, $teacher_id, $start, $end) {
    global $connection;

    $school_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $school_id);
    $teacher_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $teacher_id);
    $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $start);
    $end = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $end);

    $start = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $start);
    $end = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $end);

    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM lesson ";
    $query .= "JOIN room ON lesson.roomFK = room.roomID ";
    $query .= "JOIN school ON room.schoolFK = school.schoolID ";
    $query .= "JOIN user ON user.userID = junc_lesson_teacher.teacherFK ";
    $query .= "JOIN junc_lesson_teacher ON junc_lesson_teacher.lessonFK = lesson.lessonID ";
    $query .= "WHERE room.schoolFK = '{$school_id}' ";
    $query .= "AND lesson.startTime >= '{$start}' ";
    $query .= "AND lesson.endTime <= '{$end}' ";
    $query .= "AND user.userID = '{$teacher_id}' ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY lesson.roomFK ASC";

    $set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


    return $set;

}
```

When I run this, mySQL complains about the query statement.

Any input on how to do this properly would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: It's not returning a result set. The query is invalid.
Unknown column 'junc_lesson_teacher.teacherFK' in 'on clause'

Comment: You can't join c onto b until you've joined b onto a. There would be an error message.

Comment: From the list of tables that you supplied you don't have junc_lesson_teacher but you do have junc_lesson_user (also the fieldnames would have to be changed where appropriate if this is the correct table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your join operations is wrong. You've got to swap the last two ones. Instead of

```
$query .= "FROM lesson ";
$query .= "JOIN room ON lesson.roomFK = room.roomID ";
$query .= "JOIN school ON room.schoolFK = school.schoolID ";
$query .= "JOIN user ON user.userID = junc_lesson_teacher.teacherFK ";
$query .= "JOIN junc_lesson_teacher ON junc_lesson_teacher.lessonFK = lesson.lessonID ";
```

write

```
$query .= "FROM lesson ";
$query .= "JOIN room ON lesson.roomFK = room.roomID ";
$query .= "JOIN school ON room.schoolFK = school.schoolID ";
$query .= "JOIN junc_lesson_teacher ON junc_lesson_teacher.lessonFK = lesson.lessonID ";
$query .= "JOIN user ON user.userID = junc_lesson_teacher.teacherFK ";
```

because every table you use in a join must be introduced first. By your statement you can't use `junc_lesson_teacher` to join the `user` table, so you've got to join `junc_lesson_teacher` before you join user. Think of your tables as a chain without interrupts.

Comment: Still, I cant stand all those `"$query .="` thingies. Yuk.

Comment: @Strawberry You're right. And the use of a prepared statement with parameters to bind the input values to would enhance this query too. I think of all those questions with only a missing blank ...

Answer (score 1):

If you had a moderately sensible naming policy, that query might look like this...

```
$query = "
SELECT columns
     , i
     , actually
     , want
  FROM lesson l
  JOIN room r
    ON r.room_id = l.room_id 
  JOIN school s
    ON s.school_id = r.school_id
  JOIN lesson_teacher lt           -- <-- NOTE TABLES SWAPPED AROUND
    ON lt.lesson_id = l.lesson_id    
  JOIN user u
    ON u.user_id = lt.teacher_id  -- <-- SEE?
 WHERE r.school_id  = $school_id   
   AND l.startTime >= '$start' 
   AND l.endTime   <= '$end' 
   AND u.user_id    = $teacher_id 
 ORDER 
    BY l.room_id ASC;
";

$set = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
  or die(mysqli_error($connection)); -- for development only
```

Comment: +1 for addressing the main issue and avoiding the error prone string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$query = "SELECT * ";
```

write all of required fields from all tables

```
$query = "SELECT lesson.roomFK,room.roomID,school.schoolID,room.schoolFK,user.userID,junc_lesson_teacher.teacherFK,junc_lesson_teacher.lessonFK,lesson.lessonID";
```

Comment: There are more fields on all the tables such as username, group, email, etc which I also need. I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Guy. This is a comment, not an answer - but Dr. Neo waated to use the answer window formatting options